# Converting horizontal forces to elliptical

Tags: physics

[image: questiong description]

I'm trying to express the forces equations in point C. But not with the expected Vertical X or Y, i want to show them as a function of the angle "alpha"

i think that 
Mg ==> Mg * cos(Alpha) is correct.
but I can't understand how to express the Normal
N = ?

Comment: Seems better suited to [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com) unless you edit to include a code implementation aspect.

Comment: The magnitude of N will depend on the velocity of the object when it reaches that point. If you want us to solve the whole problem for you, you should tell us whether there's friction involved.

Comment: Wow am I missing something? where is some background info to the image (about what it represents). Already comment and Answer but what is the question about? image implies moving square object  from A to ?, how it is bounded to the trajectory?,it is accelerated?, are there any other forces then gravity present (frictions...)?  but the image can represent many different things so which one is it? Also on image is circular path not elliptical so may be describing which semi-axis is bigger would be a good start

Comment: i know i probably missed the correct physics term, I dont study physics in English so its quit hard to convert.
and i am not trying to get you solve the entire question just a better understanding of expressing the forces.
in this question we dont have friction.
and just like i tried expressing the force "Mg" im trying to figure out if "N" could also be expressed differently in a geometric way.

Comment: You want to express N in terms of M, g, alpha, S, V0, and R (the radius, the distance from O to B), is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The projection of the `Mg` vector onto the radius is `Mg * cos(Beta)`, where `Beta` is the angle between `Mg` and the radius. And given that `Alpha + Beta + 90 = 180`, we get `Beta = 90 - Alpha`. So the answer is `Mg * cos(90 - Alpha)` from `C` to the center `O`.